# Wann muss man Präpositionen mit Rücksicht auf das Genus wiederholen?

Tags: preposition

Meine Kollegen und ich sind alle Muttersprachler.

Die meisten von uns denken, man dürfe nicht sagen:

> Einzelheiten zum Erfolg oder der Natur dieser Kampagnen...,

weil „Natur“ weiblich ist.  Erlaubt sei nur:

> Einzelheiten zum Erfolg oder zur Natur dieser Kampagnen...

Ich war eigentlich der Meinung beides sei zulässig, bin aber jetzt völlig durcheinander. Dann ist uns das Beispiel eingefallen:

> Vom Tage und der Nacht davor...

Das störte keinen von uns. Ist die erste Form wirklich falsch? Gibt es für sie Beispiele in der guten Literatur?

Wie ist es, wenn kein bestimmter Artikel folgt?

> Vom/Zum Einhorn Heribert und seiner Suche nach einer Jungfrau.

Comment: Interessante Frage. Offensichtlich kann man auch sagen "Einzelheiten zu dem Erfolg oder der Natur ...", also wenn man keine Verkürzung benutzt. Irgendwo gibt es dazu bestimmt eine Regel

Comment: Es ist zumindest unschön, einmal zusammen zu ziehen ("zum") und einmal nicht ("der"). Aber falsch?

Comment: @IQV ich weiß nicht. Ich bin jetzt sehr verunsichert. Ich hätte womöglich gesagt, es sei unschön ‚zu‘ zu wiederholen. Ich werde die Augen offen halten und im Laufe der Zeit Beispiele sammeln, wie Zweig, Mann und so weiter solches vermieden. Es wird aber lange dauern.

Comment: Das erste Beispiel klingt in meinen Ohren richtig (vermutlich weil es auch als "Einzelheiten zum Erfolg oder Einzelheiten der Natur..." verstanden werden kann), das "Vom Tage und der Nacht davor..." klingt für mich dagegen gewöhnungsbedürftig. Ich meine, im Duden Band 4 "Grammatik" gab es einen Absatz zum Thema "Präp Art1 Subst1 und/oder Art2 Subst2", hab es jetzt aber nicht zur Hand; kann mich aber auch nicht erinnern, ob darin etwas über den Fall stand, dass die Präp und Art zusammengezogen sind. Ich denke, das ist ein Grenzfall der intuitiven Muttersprachler-Akzeptanz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Google Books Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams) schafft Aufklärung! :-)

Eingegeben habe ich die Wortfolgen (Ngrams) aus der Frage und weitere,
deren häufigeres Auftreten - wenn existent - ich vermutete:

1. *zum Erfolg oder der*
2. *zum Erfolg oder zur*
3. *zum Wesen oder der*
4. *zum Wesen oder zur*
5. *vom Tage und der*
6. *zur Natur und dem*

Als *zum Erfolg oder der* und *zum Wesen oder der* mit "Ngrams not found" quittiert wurde, war ich schon fast dabei, die Fronten zu wechseln. Das Ngram *zur Natur und dem* hielt mich jedoch davon ab und brachte die endgültige Aufklärung:

[image: Erwähnungshäufigkeit verschiedener Wortfolgen]

Hier auch eine exemplarische Auswahl der [Google-Suche](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22zur%20natur%20und%20dem%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_de&gws_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=hIIJWpuCJ8jQsAfis7_ADw) über *zur Natur und dem* mit Jahresangabe der Textentstehung:

- 2005: "Die Liebe zur Natur und dem sich zu erschließenden Landschaftsoder Personencharakter..."
- 1828: "Die Beziehungen zur Natur und dem Leibe sind nicht die nächsten und wesentlichen..."
- 2014: "Traurig dachte sie an Quentin und seine Liebe zur Natur und dem Wechsel der Jahreszeiten."
- 2011: "Schließlich war ihr Leben einfacher, ihr Denken rudimentärer und ihre Verbindung zur Natur und dem Heiligen weit stärker."

---

**Und damit als Fazit zurück zur ursprünglichen Frage und der Antwort darauf:**

Nein, die erste Form ist **nicht** falsch.
Ja, es gibt für sie Beispiele in der guten Literatur, sogar viele: siehe oben.